# MySQL - Alter table syntax in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, alter-table

I've created a stored procedure to change the column name as below.

Table structure:

``` CREATE TABLE ``procedurecheck`` (
 ``id`` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ``colname`` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 ``proccheck1`` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (``id``)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ```

`This is a test code only to check procedures.`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updateColumn(IN COLNAME varchar (50), IN NEWCOLNAME varchar (50))
BEGIN
  SET @ddl = CONCAT('alter table procedurecheck CHANGE (', COLNAME, ' ', NEWCOLNAME, ' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)');
  PREPARE STMT FROM @ddl;
  EXECUTE STMT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i call this function using:

`CALL updateColumn('proccheck','newproccheck');`

i get an error as follws:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(proccheck newproccheck VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)' at line 1`

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: remove `()`, eg. `CONCAT('alter table procedurecheck CHANGE ', COLNAME, ' ', NEWCOLNAME, ' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL');`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JW웃. It worked great. Please put that as answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `()`, eg.

```
CONCAT('alter table procedurecheck CHANGE ', COLNAME, ' ', NEWCOLNAME, ' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pl_updateColumnName;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE pl_updateColumnName(IN tblName varchar (50), IN COLNAME varchar (50), IN NEWCOLNAME varchar (50))
BEGIN
  SET @ddl = CONCAT(' alter table ', tblName  ,' CHANGE ', COLNAME, ' ', NEWCOLNAME, ' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL');
  PREPARE STMT FROM @ddl;
  EXECUTE STMT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try this stored proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pl_alterColumnName;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE pl_alterColumnName(IN tblName varchar (50), IN COLNAME varchar (50), IN NEWCOLNAME varchar (50))
BEGIN
  SET @ddl = CONCAT(' alter table ', tblName  ,' CHANGE ', COLNAME, ' ', NEWCOLNAME, ' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL');
  PREPARE STMT FROM @ddl;
  EXECUTE STMT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```